# Reading between rows x & y from Excel sheet through OleDbDataAdapter

Tags: vb.net, excel, ado.net, oledb

I want to read an Excel sheet into a DataTable using an OleDbDataAdapter, however, I only want a section of the spreadsheet (the part that 'looks like a database'). Here is my code so far:

```
Dim xls As String = "...fn.xls"
Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=...")
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dt As DataTable = new DataTable
Dim sql As String

conn.Open()
sql = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]" 'this is where I want between rows x & y
da = NewOleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)
da.Fill(dt)
```

Is this possible?

Thanks, 
Logan

Comment: Checkout 'CurrentRegion`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can do two things that work:

Name a range and then select from it.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM [RangeName]" ' does not end with $
```

or

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A1:Z10]" ' sheetname$excelrange
```

I didn't know about the RangeName bit and guessed about the row/cell specifics

My source: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/537809-c-oledb-issue